PowerBI Desktop: Conditional formatting min & max
I would like to color the maximum data in a table in green and the minimum data in red. The table has 1500 rows and I want the formatting to be present on the "supplier" and "CA N" column, from the max and min value of the "Var.CA" column. Can you help me? THANKS

I searched for dax formulas with artificial intelligence but it didn't work

Its a two step process, first create a variable to show max and min and then configure the conditional formatting of the table so that it uses the information provided by the MinMax measure to colour the cell background by using the based on field.
Step 1
MinMax =
VAR Vals =
    CALCULATETABLE(
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE ( Sales, Sales[Fournisseur],etc ),
            "@CAN", [CA N]
        ),
        ALLSELECTED ()
    )
VAR MinValue = MINX ( Vals, [@CAN] )
VAR MaxValue = MAXX ( Vals, [@CAN] )
VAR CurrentValue = [CA N]
VAR Result =
    SWITCH (
        TRUE,
        CurrentValue = MinValue, 1, -- 1 for MIN
        CurrentValue = MaxValue, 2  -- 2 for MAX
    )
RETURN
    Result

Then Step 2

Select format visual
Select Background colour to be "On"
click on FX
Change format style from gradient to rules
Change the "what field should we base this on" to MinMax
Change rules so 1 = Red and 2 = Green

